# Extend django auth login view

Tags: python, django, authentication

Just getting to grips with Django and Python. I'm trying to implement ajax login. Is it possible to do this by extending the native auth class or do I have to completely rewrite. I'm really trying to retrieve error messages as JSON.

Answer (score 5):

You can quite easily write an ajax view to handle login:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
def ajax_login(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
    logged_in = False
    if request.is_ajax() and form.is_valid():
        login(request, user)
        logged_in = True
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({ 'logged_in' : logged_in}), mimetype='application/json')
```

and an url:

```
url(r'^ajax/login/$', 'myapp.views.ajax_login',name="ajax_login"),
```

Have a look [at the docs for more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.login)